# How to set the default url when i run server in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django, When I run server, default url always come out with http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

But i want justin http://127.0.0.1:8000 url for start.

How can i change the default of url?

In urls.py, there are no redirectview function.

This is my app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from . import views

app_name = 'jack'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/jack/', permanent=True))
]
```

and this is my project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
path('jack/', include('jack.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/jack/', permanent=True))
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your project `urls.py` you set the path to the jack app to use `127.0.0.1:8000/jack`

change the path to look like this :
`path('', include('jack.urls')),`

and you can remove this:
`path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/jack/', permanent=True))`

Comment: After you remove the redirect, the permanent=True means the browser might continue to redirect. If this happens, then you can clear your browser cache or use a different browser.